# How to replace a specific value in an entire CSV file with pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a large csv file that I import to pandas. The first row is the header of columns (even if it is values). My goal is to replace all values of -999.999 to 0.

I have already tried to make my first row as header with df.colums = df.iloc[0] but without success. To replace the values I tried to use df.replace but it does not seem to find the -999.99 values.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('Test.csv') # importer le dossier CSV 

df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df.replace(-999.999, 0, inplace=True)

df.to_csv('test2.csv')
```

The CSV file looks like this where the first column (0-1-2...) was automatically created and not part of the original data.

```
  -120;-119.7;-119.4;-119.1;-118.8;-118.5;-118.2;-117.9
0  -999.999;-999.999;-999.999;20.1;1.2;89.5;-999....   
1  -999.999;-999.999;4.6;25.6;8.9;-999.999;-999.9...   
2  -999.999;-999.999;8.66;12.6;7.6;-999.999;13.98...   
3  -999.999;-999.999;9.12;6.98;0.6;45.3;12.4;-999...   
4  -999.999;-999.999;13.36;4.56;3.9;2.36;-999.999...   
5  -999.999;-999.999;-999.999;21;45.2;-999.999;-9...
```

Comment: Is it possible your data is loading as strings and not floats?  After pd.read_csv, show `df.info()` in this question.

Comment: df.info() gives out this :
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 6 entries, 0 to 5
Data columns (total 1 columns):
-120;-119.7;-119.4;-119.1;-118.8;-118.5;-118.2;-117.9    6 non-null object
dtypes: object(1)
memory usage: 128.0+ bytes

Comment: > The CSV file looks like this where the first column (0-1-2...) was automatically created ...

That's something called an index (`pd.Index`) if you wanted to do some research

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First problem is that you need to specify the separator the second problem with `replace` is that it will be converted to `float64` so using `replace(-999.999, 0)` will not work.

```
from io import StringIO

s = '''-120;-119.7;-119.4;-119.1;-118.8;-118.5;-118.2;-117.9
-999.999;-999.999;-999.999;20.1;1.2;89.5;-999
-999.999;-999.999;4.6;25.6;8.9;-999.999;-999.9
-999.999;-999.999;8.66;12.6;7.6;-999.999;13.98
-999.999;-999.999;9.12;6.98;0.6;45.3;12.4;-999
-999.999;-999.999;13.36;4.56;3.9;2.36;-999.999
-999.999;-999.999;-999.999;21;45.2;-999.999;-9'''

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), sep=';')

df = df.replace(df.iloc[0,0], 0) # specify a cell with the value you want to replace
```

or you can use a `float64` number:

```
df.replace(-999.9989999999999, 0)

   -120  -119.7  -119.4  -119.1  -118.8  -118.5  -118.2  -117.9
0   0.0     0.0    0.00   20.10     1.2   89.50 -999.00     NaN
1   0.0     0.0    4.60   25.60     8.9    0.00 -999.90     NaN
2   0.0     0.0    8.66   12.60     7.6    0.00   13.98     NaN
3   0.0     0.0    9.12    6.98     0.6   45.30   12.40  -999.0
4   0.0     0.0   13.36    4.56     3.9    2.36    0.00     NaN
5   0.0     0.0    0.00   21.00    45.2    0.00   -9.00     NaN
```

For an actual file `StringIO` will be replaced with the file path.

The first column, as you call it, is the `index` if you do not want it in the output just `df.to_csv('file.csv', index=False)`

Answer (score 0):

`pd.read_csv()` uses a default separator `','` - please pass the argument `sep=';'` for your data. To eliminate the index in the output just pass the argument `index=False` to `df.to_csv()`.